# Thesis template for beginers

Tags: templates

I am new to LaTex, though I wrote three research papers in LaTex with the help of this forum. Thanks to all users, who answered my queries. I found LaTex very interesting and am motivated to write my Ph. D thesis in LaTex. However, there are a number of templates available and I am slightly confused, which one should I choose. Our Institute does not have any specific template. Kindly suggest which one will be easier for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already pointed out, there is a wide variety of templates. To get started you could have a look at this guide: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html

To get a quick overview about classes that provide functionality for writing a thesis and their traps, [A university thesis class: Automation and its pitfalls](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-2/tb104flynn.pdf) can be really helpful.

While I myself use [`cleanthesis`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleanthesis?lang=de), it mostly depends on what you like personally.